Google App Engine Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations
I am using Google App Engine using runtime nodejs20 with a typescript server. Everything builds + runs locally, but on deploy, I am getting Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations. I recently had to start using code in a directory outside where the app.yaml is located, so I think it's because of that, but not sure how to fix.
My directory structure:
api
- app.yaml
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
- <my api code which uses things in shared/database
shared
- database
- - DatabaseModel.ts
- - <other shared files I need>

The error occurs when I use files like DatabaseModel inside /api folder and try to deploy. However, it works locally (builds + runs).
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build d620cd15-1263-4441-90f9-26b72693f1ac status: FAILURE
> api@1.0.0 gcp-build
> tsc -p .

Customer.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../shared/database/DatabaseModel' or its corresponding type declarations.
...(and more like this)

Things I tried:
(a) Use includes in app.yaml.
includes:
- ../shared/**/*

Got error, so I assume I'm setting the value or using this property wrong?
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [app.yaml]
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "shared/database/DatabaseModel.ts", line 2, column 22

(b)
Setting include in my tsconfig.json
 "include": [
    "../shared/database/DatabaseModel.ts",
  ],

or with wildcards:
 "include": [
    "../shared/**/*,
  ],

But also got the error:
error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file '/workspace/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../shared/database/DatabaseModel.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'.

